# Ms Access relationship between two different type of field

Tags: ms-access, relationship

I have a trusted MS Access database about invoices, procurement. I use it 4 years ago now, but need a re-do, to solve problems, build new things in to it, make it more easier to use. I started using MS Access more then a decade ago, but this is the first time I must ask.

I have only one problem doing that.
I have two tables which has a relationship, one-to-many. One is about invoice data, the other is invoice items. In the invoice table the invoice number is an autonumber with a specified format. There is a split form, where should be a filtered datasheet, filtered to the actual invoice numbers. Now it is not working, because the two connected field parameters are not match.
Yes the one is auto number, the other stored as short text.

In the old database I stored the invoice number as short text, but I hate to fill a new invoice number all the time when I create one. This must be a new feature to the database, to fill it automatically.

For more precise information:
Invoice number:
Data type: autonumber
Field size: Long integer
New values: Increment
Format: "SZ"00000

If you believe my approach is not ideal, your ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert either number and then filter/compare/match as you need:

```
NumericNumber = Val([TextNumber])
```

or:

```
TextNumber = CStr([NumericNumber])
```

If "SZ" is prefixed the text number, try:

```
TextNumber = "SZ" & CStr([NumericNumber])
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav! I modified the original post with more information.

Comment: OK. See expanded answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

Good database design principles suggest that you should add the invoice number *as a number* to the Invoice Items table. Then you would also be able to set the invoice number as a foreign key, which would help you to enforce [referential integrity](https://database.guide/what-is-referential-integrity/#:%7E:text=Referential%20integrity%20refers%20to%20the,%E2%80%93%20or%20parent%20%E2%80%93%20table) between the two tables. You can format the number as required when you read the table.